# Convert Ordered Dictionary to PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data dict which is ordered

```
OrderedDict([('name', ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']), ('age', [10,12,13])])
```

How to convert this dictionary to PySpark dataframe?

Expected Output

```
Name age
---  ---
aaa  10
bbb  12
ccc  13
```

Comment: why you need `OrderedDict`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = OrderedDict([('name', ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']), ('age', [10,12,13])])

spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d)).show()
# +----+---+
# |name|age|
# +----+---+
# | aaa| 10|
# | bbb| 12|
# | ccc| 13|
# +----+---+
```

This should work as well

```
spark.createDataFrame(zip(*d.values()), list(d.keys()))
```

but won't use Arrow optimizations.

But:

- Don't get attached to the order. In general Spark `DataFrame` behaves like a relation (shouldn't be consider ordered, unless `ORDER(ED) BY`).
- Converting local objects to distributed ones, has very limited applications, as all data has to be preserved in the driver memory.

Comment: I would underline the fact that order in spark isn't preserved. So it's clear for the OP. :)

Comment: @eliasah Well, I wouldn't go so far. I can guarantee that order won't change here, no matter how many times this code is executed. It is more that thinking about order is a dead end, and sooner or later, will cause some dire mistake ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without invoking pandas?